Python Web Scraping Issue: Missing Pagination Elements When Loading Autotrader Website Programmatically
hello my problem is that when my Python program loads a website called Autotraders when it opens the website, multiple things are missing from the website.
like in the following
when I open it
https://i.sstatic.net/LhWVUsYd.png
when the program opens it
https://i.sstatic.net/jtCIjOyF.png
the pages don't pop up which is bad because my program needs to check every page so when it looks at the HTML for the button that switches pages it's not their. I even checked it myself by going into the inspect element doing ctrl + F and searching for page 1 nothing popped up
here is my code
https://pastebin.com/meZXCDkK
here is the relevant part of my code which breaks every time because of the site not fully loading
        pagination_container = content.find('div', {'data-cmp': 'cntnr-pagination'})

the line of code above always returns none because the web page that the program opens does not have the pagination(basically the pages) at all and I don't know why
I think this is an issue because of the site but I want to make sure

When you open it, is there a pageSize parameter (or something similar) in the URL? If so, you may need to add it to the URL in the request your code is generating.

here is the exact html that my code opens based on what i type in the console:
https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/cars-under-10000/denver-co?0=vehicledetails.xhtml&maxMileage=100000&searchRadius=50&zip=80202&marketExtension=include&isNewSearch=false&showAccelerateBanner=false&sortBy=relevance&numRecords=25&firstRecord=50
and the one i open is exactly the same link, also couldnt find a pagesize parameter when i just googled the page and then added the filters

That URL is different from the one in your Pastebin code, which is https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/all-cars/ followed by a number of parameters. And that URL includes numRecords and firstRecord parameters, which is how autotrader is doing pagination. Consider incrementing firstRecord repeatedly by numRecords until you get a 404, rather than trying to figure out how many pages their are. That might be easier.

sorry but i cannot find what you mean here is the link i get from my code https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/all-cars/cars-between-1-and-100000/honda/civic/coraopolis-pa?endYear=2020&mileage=45000&newSearch=true&price-from=1&searchRadius=500&startYear=2010&vehicleHistoryType=CLEAN_TITLE
and here is the one from searching
https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/all-cars/cars-between-1-and-100000/honda/civic/coraopolis-pa?endYear=2020&mileage=45000&newSearch=true&price-from=1&searchRadius=500&startYear=2010&vehicleHistoryType=CLEAN_TITLE
exactly the same
